# fork() failing with Out of memory error

Tags: linux, fork, virtual-memory, memory-overcommitment

The parent process fails with errno=12(Out of memory) when it tries to fork a child. The parent process runs on Linux 3.0 kernel - SLES 11. At the point of forking the child, the parent process has already used up around 70% of the RAM(180GB/256GB). Is there any workaround for this problem?

The application is written in C++, compiled with g++ 4.6.3.

Comment: I cannot answer as I do not have a forking idea. Need a little information

Comment: You may be running into OS limits, refer to setrlimit

Comment: The question you should have really asked is how to print a backtrace, not how to make `fork` work; you didn't tell -except in recent comments- that you are forking to run `gdb` then its `bt` command!

Answer (score 13):

Maybe virtual memory over commit is prevented in your system.

If it is prevented, then the virtual memory can not be bigger than sizeof physical RAM + swap. If it is allowed, then virtual memory can be bigger than RAM+swap.

When your process forks, your processes (parent and child) would have 2*180GB of virtual memory (that is too much if you don't have swap).

So, allow over commit by this way:

```
 echo 1 > /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
```

It should help, if child process execves immediately, or frees allocated memory before the parent writes too much to own memory. So, be careful, out of memory killer may act if both processes keep using all the memory.

man page of proc(5) says:

> /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_memory
>
> This file contains the kernel virtual
>   memory accounting mode. Values are: 0: heuristic overcommit (this is
>   the default) 1: always overcommit, never check 2: always check, never
>   overcommit
>
> In mode 0, calls of mmap(2) with MAP_NORESERVE are not checked, and
>   the default check is very weak, leading to the risk of getting a
>   process "OOM-killed". Under Linux 2.4 any nonzero value implies mode
>   1. In mode 2 (available since Linux 2.6), the total virtual address space on the system is limited to (SS + RAM*(r/100)), where SS is the
>   size of the swap space, and RAM is the size of the physical memory,
>   and r is the contents of the file /proc/sys/vm/overcommit_ratio.

More information here: [Overcommit Memory in SLES](http://www.novell.com/support/kb/doc.php?id=7002775)

Comment: This is helpful, but may be of dangerous consequence for the normal operation of the process.

Comment: @Basile Starynkevitch : yes, it is not so safe. Warning added to the answer.

Comment: Very helpful indeed! sure you should know the actual memory usage of both parent and child.

Answer (score 1):

`fork`-ing requires resources, since it is [copy-on-writing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Copy-on-write) the writable pages of the process. Read again the [fork(2)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/fork.2.html) man page.

You could at least provide a huge temporary swap file. You could create (on some file system with enough space) a huge file `$SWAPFILE` with

```
  dd if=/dev/zero of=$SWAPFILE bs=1M count=256000
  mkswap $SWAPFILE
  swapon $SWAPFILE
```

Otherwise, you could for instance design your program differently, e.g. `mmap`-ing some big file (and `munmap`-ing it just before the fork, and `mmap`-ing it again after), or more simply starting at the beginning of your program a `popen`-ed shell, or a `p2open`-ed one or making explicitly the `pipe`-s to and from it (probably a multiplexing call à la `poll` would also be useful), and later issue commands to it.

Maybe we could help more if we had an idea of what your program is doing, why does it consume so much memory, and why and what is it forking...

Read [Advanced Linux Programming](http://advancedlinuxprogramming.com/) for more.

#### PS.

If you `fork` just to run `gdb` to show the backtrace, consider simpler alternatives like [recent GCC's libbacktrace](https://github.com/mirrors/gcc/tree/master/libbacktrace) or [Wolf's libbacktrace](http://freecode.com/projects/libbacktrace)...

Comment: I'm trying to invoke a non-interactive gdb session to get full backtrace. Huge memory usage is due to the requirements of the application. It is expected and not due to any leaks.

Comment: the suggestion of starting a popen()ed shell seems to be a nice idea but is it possible to start a bi-directional pipe for read and write?

Comment: You could also use `libbacktrace` or simply run `gdb` interactively with its `-p $pidnumber` argument.

Answer (score 0):

A nicer solution on Linux would be to use vfork or posix_spawn (as it will try to use vfork if possible): vfork "creates new processes without copying the page tables of the parent process", so it will work even if your application uses more than 50% of RAM available.

Note that std::system and QProcess::execute also use fork under the hood, there is even a ticket about this problem in Qt framework: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-17331